# v8 (javascript) String::New asserted

Tags: javascript, string, assert, v8, garbage

I work with v8 (google's javascript engine) recently. When the GC is running, String::New always trigger a assert at ASSERT(state_ != NEAR_DEATH)(global-handles.cc 237line). Does have some suggestion.

Here is some of my source snippet:

```
void javascript_ctx_impl::call_obj_func (v8::persistent<object> object, const char* method, int argc, handle<value> argv[]) 
{ 
    handlescope handle_scope; 
    local<value> cb = object->get(string::new(method)); 
    if (!cb->isfunction()) { 
        std::cerr << "method = " << method << std::endl; 
                return; 
    } 
    local<function> do_action = local<function>::cast(cb); 
    trycatch try_catch; 
    /**ASSERT HERE **/
    **do_action->call(object, argc, argv);** 
    /**ASSERT HERE **/
    if (try_catch.hascaught()) { 
                v8::local<v8::message> msg = try_catch.message (); 
        if (!msg->getscriptresourcename().isempty() && !msg- 
>getscriptresourcename()->isundefined()) 

        { 
            v8::string::asciivalue name (msg- 
>getscriptresourcename()); 

            std::cerr << *name << std::endl; 
        } 
        else { 
            std::cerr << "call_obj_func: runtime error." << std::endl; 
        } 
    } 
} 

template <typename T> 
class write_handle : public handle_impl_base 
{ 
    public: 
       write_handle (boost::asio::io_service& io, v8::Persistent<Object> 
local,v8::Persistent<Object> h) 
       : handle_impl_base (io), handle_ (h), session_ (local) 
       { 
       } 
    public: 
        void operator () (const boost::system::error_code& ec, 
std::size_t bytes_transferred) 
        { 
            HandleScope handle_scope; 
            if (!ec) { 
                Handle<Value> args[3] = { 
                    js::instance ().safe_new_value (session_), 
                                        js::instance ().safe_new_value ("TRUE"), 
                                        js::instance ().safe_new_value (bytes_transferred) 
                }; 
                                js::instance ().call_obj_func (handle_, "onHandle", 3, args); 
            } 
            else { 
                Handle<Value> args[3] = { 
                    js::instance ().safe_new_value (session_), 
                                        js::instance ().safe_new_value ("FALSE"), 
                                        js::instance ().safe_new_value (bytes_transferred) 
                }; 
                                js::instance ().call_obj_func (handle_, "onHandle", 3, args); 
            } 
            handle_.Dispose (); session_.Dispose (); 
        } 
        static void handle_weak (Persistent<Value> object, void* 
parameter) 
        { 
            object.Dispose ();
        } 
    private: 
        v8::Persistent<Object> handle_; 
        v8::Persistent<Object> session_; 
}; 

v8::Handle<v8::Value> js_asio_socket_ip_tcp_function::async_write (const v8::Arguments& args) 
{ 
    HandleScope hScope; 
    js_asio_socket_ip_tcp_function* native_obj = 
unwrap<js_asio_socket_ip_tcp_function>(args.This()); 
    if (args.Length () < 4) { 
        return ThrowException (Exception::TypeError(String::New( 
                        "async_resolve need 4 parameters.")) 
                ); 
    } 
    /** Argument check here */ 
    js_stream_function* s = unwrap<js_stream_function> (args[1]- 
>ToObject ()); 

    if (s == NULL) { 
        return ThrowException (Exception::TypeError(String::New( 
                        "async_resolve parameter 2 error.")) 
                ); 
    } 
    v8::Local<v8::Object>  p0 = args[0]->ToObject (); 
    v8::Local<v8::Integer> p2 = args[2]->ToUint32 (); 
    v8::Persistent<Object> handle; 
    v8::Persistent<Object> sessin; 
    if (args[3]->ToObject ()->IsFunction ()) { 
        v8::Local<v8::Function> f = v8::Local<v8::Function>::Cast(args[3]->ToObject()); 
        handle = v8::Persistent<v8::Object>::New(f); 
    } 
    else { 
        handle = v8::Persistent<Object>::New (args[3]->ToObject ()); 
    } 
    handle.MakeWeak (NULL, write_handle<void>::handle_weak); 
    handle.MarkIndependent (); 
    sessin = v8::Persistent<Object>::New (p0); 
    boost::asio::async_write (*(native_obj->socket_), 
            boost::asio::buffer (s->get (), p2->Value ()), 
            boost::asio::transfer_all (), 
            make_concrete_handle (write_handle <void> (native_obj- 
>socket_->get_io_service (), sessin, handle) 

                ) 
            ); 
    return v8::Undefined (); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `write_handle<T>::handle_weak` is empty. It should **never** be empty as this violates its contract documented at https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/include/v8.h#L124-132

Comment: I tried it. put object.Dispose () in there. same problem. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I did that, Sill assert. Thanks for your patient. Any more suggestion?  It pushes me crazy.
actually source never run into handle_weak () function

Comment: Is this the whole code or you have some other weak callbacks?

Comment: In debugger when assertion triggers you should go up to the frame which corresponds to `Node::PostGarbageCollectionProcessing` and then inspect variable called `func` which points to offending callback. This will tell you which callback does not follow the contract.

Comment: Is there any possiable that the parameters, some parameters is constructed by String::New. I am not understand about how GC to manage String::New's memory. But String::New returns a Local<Type> value. I can't call MakeWeak with that handle.

Comment: I updated the weak callback function. please take a look the function handle_weak.

Comment: Thanks Vyacheslav Egorov, I just found that in the google groups is you too. It's really nice of you.

Comment: The func is a hint for me. I am trying to figure out.

Comment: No `String::New` does not use weak handles. It just triggers GC when it can't allocate, which triggers processing of weak handles. Now your `handle_weak` looks correct. What does debugger tell you? If you want to proceed you need to figure out which callback is misbehaving so you need to inspect that `func` variable.

Comment: PostGarbageCollectionProcessing a little confusing about this funciton, This function try to change the value of state_, the func is setted and called corrected. after that call, state_ still is NEAR_DEATH. Is it normal? If it is right, each time source run into PostGarbageCollectionProcessing asserted.

Comment: Hi  Vyacheslav Egorov, The problem is fixed. You a right, It's the pointer problem. Thank you again. Thank you. Thank you. Thank you very much really.